Deno log INFO and WARN to different files
I'm trying to log .info and .warn messages to different files, but all goes to the default file whereas the other is empty.
const infoFileHandler = new log.RotatingFileHandler("INFO", { 
    filename: 'log.log',
    maxBytes: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
    maxBackupCount: 5
});

const warnFileHandler = new log.RotatingFileHandler("WARN", { 
    filename: 'log-warn.log',
    maxBytes: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
    maxBackupCount: 5
});


// Flush every second
setInterval(() => {
    infoFileHandler.flush();
    warnFileHandler.flush();
}, 1000);

log.setup({
    handlers: {
        default: infoFileHandler,
        warn: warnFileHandler
    },
    loggers: {
        default: { level: "INFO", handlers: ["info"] },
        warn: { level: "WARN", handlers: ["warn"] }
    }
})

const logger = log.getLogger();
logger.info("info message");
logger.warn("warning message");

Both files log.log and log-warn.log are created but all messages goes to log.log
EDIT:
Ok, I've figured out the problem.
I need to use log.getLogger().info("...") for info messages and log.getLogger('warn').warn("...") for warnings

Since there is nothing actionable for this question, should it be closed?

Ok, I've figured out the problem. I need to use log.getLogger().info("...") for info messages and log.getLogger('warn').warn("...") for warnings
